# Module WSGI don't recognize by Heroku

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, wsgi, django-wsgi

I'm deploying Django==2.1 with Python==3.6.5 on Heroku and the push works fine but when I go to the link appears application error.

The log says me that wigs module doesn't exist:

```
$ heroku logs --tail

2018-10-11T10:19:04.796988+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2018-10-11T10:19:04.801708+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'healthylife.wsgi'
2018-10-11T10:19:04.801978+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-10-11 10:19:04 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
```

But I have revised and I think it's ok:

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn healthylife.wsgi --log-file -
```

settings.py:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'healthylife.wsgi.application'
```

wsgi.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "healthylife.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()

if not settings.DEBUG:
    try:
        from dj_static import Cling
        application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
    except:
        pass
```

Someone could help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide repo with all code.

Comment: GitHub repository:   https://github.com/AlbertoSanmartinMartinez/HealthyLifeWeb

Comment: is it work without `Cling` import?

Comment: does't work either

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in a project structure. 
Try to change in Procfile place with wsgi file

`web: gunicorn healthylife.healthylife.wsgi`

Comment: I dunno, try to deploy the brand new Heroku template and move your project into it.

Comment: SOLVED. The problem was the structure of the project, it had a folder coming from the repository called the same as the project.

Comment: I have a similar situation. All the suggestions here didn't work for me. Can you help look at it please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63465541/django-vuejs-app-deployed-to-heroku-showing-application-error-on-page

Comment: @banky you have to check the path to your wsgi file

Comment: I have updated my question with the path/layout of my project. Please have a look